# Python 2.7. Cómo eliminar paréntesis cuadrados en archivo .txt de tipo numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

tengo un archivo .txt de tipo numpy.ndarray (una solo columna) muy grande de la siguiente forma:

```
[[  3]
 [ 10]
 [  1]
 [  3]
 [ 31]
 [254]]
```

y quiero eliminar todos los paréntesis y generar un nuevo archivo .txt de esta forma:

```
3
10
1
3
31
254
```

Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? puedes agregar algo de código a tu pregunta.

Comment: donde esta codigo como vamos a ayudar si no sabemos lo que escribiste. No somos genios.

Comment: @Lucas probó la respuesta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui esta lo que necesitas para quitar los corchetes:

> re.sub(r'[\[\]]', "", **text_de_entrada**)

Ahora el programa que resuelve tu problema:

```
import re

inn = ''
with open('numpy.ndarray', 'r') as file:
    inn = file.read()

with open('archivo.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(re.sub(r'[\[\]]', '', inn))
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas Python para eso? usa sólo un procesador de texto como notepad++.
`ctrl+f`, Usas `find` and `replace all` encuentras los elementos `[` o `]` y los reemplazas por nada.